# Making custom shape imageview ios swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios. I am trying to make the bottom border(not left of right the whole bottom) of image view into curve. Anyone can guide me how to do it.

[Here is the image of the border i want to acheive:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHJGE.png)

[image]

Comment: Which corner you want curve of imageView?

Comment: i added the image to further clearify it. The whole bottom border actually not just a corner

Comment: Is imageView inside of UIView ?

Comment: no thats just an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
func curvedShapeFor(view: UIImageView, curvedPercent:CGFloat) ->UIBezierPath
{
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:view.bounds.size.width, y:0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:view.bounds.size.width, y:view.bounds.size.height - (view.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent)))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:view.bounds.size.height - (view.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent)), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:view.bounds.size.width/2, y:view.bounds.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
    path.close()

    return path
}
```

**And apply like this way:**

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: imageView.layer)
shapeLayer.path = self.curvedShapeFor(view: imageView,curvedPercent: 0.6).cgPath
shapeLayer.frame = imageView.bounds
shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

Comment: its returning a path what should i do with it

Comment: @ChristianLizama: I have added a code at bottom for how to apply on your image view